# Could not find module (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax?

Tags: python, shapely, geos

I am trying to install greppo and this error is popping up.
Here is detail:

```
Collecting Shapely==1.7.1
  Using cached Shapely-1.7.1.tar.gz (383 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\waqas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7s68x426\shapely_7bc3527fa38249478d749a0dbc
729913\setup.py", line 85, in <module>
          from shapely._buildcfg import geos_version_string, geos_version, \
        File "C:\Users\waqas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7s68x426\shapely_7bc3527fa38249478d749a0dbc
729913\shapely\_buildcfg.py", line 205, in <module>
          lgeos = CDLL("geos_c.dll")
        File "C:\Users\waqas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374,
 in __init__
          self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
      FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'geos_c.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the
 full path with constructor syntax.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: And your question is why using the full path with constructor syntax did not help?

Comment: No it does not help

Comment: mkriger1 yes, that's it